# How do i draw a Cube in OpenGL/C++?

Tags: c++, opengl

I see a lot of people using Glbegin(GL_POLYGON) to draw cubes whats that about, I learnt this in class whats the diffrence is the way my teacher thought me worse.

```
GLfloat verts[] =
{
    -1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, // 0
    +1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, // Color
    +1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, // 1
    +0.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, // Color
    +1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, // 2
    +0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f, // Color
    -1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, // 3
    +1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, // Color

    -1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, // 4
    +1.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f, // Color
    +1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, // 5
    +0.0f, +0.5f, +0.2f, // Color
    +1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // 6
    +0.8f, +0.6f, +0.4f, // Color
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // 7
    +0.3f, +1.0f, +0.5f, // Color

    +1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, // 8
    +0.2f, +0.5f, +0.2f, // Color
    +1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, // 9
    +0.9f, +0.3f, +0.7f, // Color
    +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, // 10
    +0.3f, +0.7f, +0.5f, // Color
    +1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // 11
    +0.5f, +0.7f, +0.5f, // Color

    -1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, // 12
    +0.7f, +0.8f, +0.2f, // Color
    -1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, // 13
    +0.5f, +0.7f, +0.3f, // Color
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // 14
    +0.4f, +0.7f, +0.7f, // Color
    -1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, // 15
    +0.2f, +0.5f, +1.0f, // Color

    +1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, // 16
    +0.6f, +1.0f, +0.7f, // Color
    -1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, // 17
    +0.6f, +0.4f, +0.8f, // Color
    -1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, // 18
    +0.2f, +0.8f, +0.7f, // Color
    +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, // 19
    +0.2f, +0.7f, +1.0f, // Color

    +1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // 20
    +0.8f, +0.3f, +0.7f, // Color
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // 21
    +0.8f, +0.9f, +0.5f, // Color
    -1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, // 22
    +0.5f, +0.8f, +0.5f, // Color
    +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, // 23
    +0.9f, +1.0f, +0.2f, // Color
};

GLushort indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, // Top
    4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, // Front
    8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, // Right 
    12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, // Left
    16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, // Back
    20, 22, 21, 20, 23, 22, // Bottom
};


GLuint VertexBufferID;
glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 3));

//GLushort indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 };
GLuint indexBufferID;
glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

so im trying to use this to draw a cube but it comes out looking ike a square and when i rotate it its not a cube.

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glViewport(0, 0, width(), height());
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity(); 

GLint TriPositionUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "TriPosition");
GLint domColorUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "domColor");

vec3 domColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glUniformMatrix4fv(TriPositionUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &TriPosition[0][0]);
glUniform3fv(domColorUniformLocation, 1, &domColor[0]);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Why is no cube being drawn to the screen? what methods am i missing or what am i doing wrong?

```
mat4 moveObject(mat4 mat, int left, int up, int right, int down, float                 speed, float angle,float dt)
{
short Left = GetAsyncKeyState(left);
short Up = GetAsyncKeyState(up);
short Right = GetAsyncKeyState(right);
short Down = GetAsyncKeyState(down);

mat4 matTemp = mat;

if (Left != 0)
{
    matTemp = rotate(matTemp, angle, vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
}

if (Right != 0)
{
    matTemp = rotate(matTemp, -angle, vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
}
if (Up != 0)
{
    matTemp = translate(matTemp, vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, speed)* dt);
}
if (Down != 0)
{
    matTemp = translate(matTemp, vec3(0.0f, -speed, 0.0f)* dt);
}

return matTemp;
```

}

this is how i set triPosition i take the value returned and set triPosition equal to that.

```
#version 430

in layout(location=0) vec3 position;
in layout(location=1) vec3 vertexColor;

uniform mat4 TriPosition;
uniform vec3 domColor;

out vec3 theColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 v = vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = TriPosition * v;
    theColor = vertexColor;
};
```

My problem now is that i see the cube but i cant move it in 3d space it might be really close to my camera but i cant move it way even when pressing up.

Comment: Post the rest of the verts, even if it takes up extra space.

Comment: You should call glGetAttribLocation and use the returned value for the first parameter to glVertexAttribPointer and glEnableVertexAttribArray, unless you are specifying the location in the vertex shader (can't tell because you haven't posted it)

Comment: I think i am specifying the location in my vertex shader. in layout(location=0) vec3 position;
in layout(location=1) vec3 vertexColor;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've incorrectly specified that your vertex co-ordinates have only 2 components in your call to [glVertexAttribPointer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)(i.e. are 2 dimensional). So you get a square instead of a cube.

Second parameter should be 3:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, 0);
```

Comment: It looks to be a bit more 3d now :), there still seems to be a problem i cant get it to go further in the screen moving the matrix in the z doesn't help. The cube also has holes in it which are weird but im guessing its my camera going inside of the cube.

Comment: The things to look at to fix that would be your matrix code and your vertex shader

Comment: Three things: 1) Why are you moving along z when you press up but y when you press down? 2) check speed is not zero 3) You can check whether the problem is related to your key handling or your matrix by removing the if(Up != 0) test to make it move continually even when you are not pressing the button.

Comment: i was just trying to test my project to see if the cube would go int the screen but it didn't work even when i commented out the if(up!=0)

Comment: The OpenGL-related code looks fine. Check that speed and dt are not zero. Also you can try applying a translation when you initialize the matrix.